# Contact Relationship not showing

Tags: joomla, relationships, contact-types

I imported the data in the CIVI contact table address table, phone table  and added relationship in the civi relationship table.
the table looks correct with the data and it also showing the contacts on civi crm (Joomla) with all fields.
however the relationship tab in the contact showing empty.
in contacts reports the relationship showing fine but not in the edit contacts > relationship tab.
I tried to delete the cache from template_c folder and empty the civi relationship cache table but no sucess.

Similar issue with contact type tag is not showing correct in contact view however when edit the cotact its edited under correct type.

any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: What version are you on? In latest there has been a switch to using SK/FB (SearchKit/FormBuilder) for the Contact Relationship Tab. If you are on latest can you make sure both SK and FB are 'installed' via your Extension page

Comment: I have version  5.67.0 yes both install the relationship show blank 0

Comment: any solution on it?

Comment: no idea. try searching for 'relationship tab' at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/search-improvements. eg i found https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/54zco4xi8fy17rtj7sjxdoq5da

Answer (score 2):

got the issue and fixed. on custom import civi not detecting the value empty. some fields are empty need to set them null and its fixed.